# Top bar shows pending suggested edits but the queue is empty

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

The count flag at the top bar depicting the number of suggested edits pending approval seems to have stuck. The Suggested Edits review queue is empty already.

I tried both Firefox and Chromium browser, even the private browsing, but the issue persists.

1. Pending suggested edits count flag

   [image]
2. Relevant review queue is empty

   [image]
3. Clicking on the flag shows that the queue is empty.

   [image]

I found the related posts [Minor suggested-edits notification bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160617/286110) and [Number of suggested edits seems to include own edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109630/286110) but the questioner  in both the questions noted that he made tag wiki edits which I didn't do.

I only reviewed two suggested edits (both from anonymous users) so I'm not running empty when it comes to reviewing the suggested edits.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Update: The icon is gone for now.

Comment: I've seen this many times on SO. I'll be having 15 post in the queue but when I click the icon the queue will be empty. ;)

Comment: Did you report the issue or search about it on meta sites? May be you know about a post that can help me understand the cause here.

Comment: No. Sometimes It got cleared after a page refresh.

Comment: I thought this was due to it counting "skipped" review tasks in the notification (until others review them), despite them being filtered out on the review pages.  I think it's just caching rather than a bug, regardless.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @m0sa I'm not familiar with what caching means here. May I suggest you briefly tell  what could have lead to that issue?

Comment: there is some heavy caching on the back end for that value. that's why the label says "~2 pending suggested edits" -> "approximately two pending suggested edits"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the second part of your comment. Here's related posts that might be helpful [Why is review queue showing a number when it is empty?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1218/1699) & [Does the review queue page show only reviews requiring your action? Does it differ, and when does it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238698/205886)

Comment: @Lucky, thanks. :) Although m0sa already pointed out the cause, those links you posted are quite helpful.